# Zurb Foundation breakpoint changes not taking effect

Tags: sass, breakpoints, zurb-foundation-6

I am working with Zurb Foundation 6 for Sites within Intellij on an Ubuntu system with the native sassc compiler, and attempting to change the Foundation breakpoints.  All of the documentation I have read indicates that this is as easy as simply changing the value of the breakpoints in the settings file.

Unfortunately, when I do this, my changes have no effect.  I am hoping that someone can show me what I am doing wrong.

I have searched the web and find nothing regarding troubleshooting changing breakpoints, so I expect this is drop-dead simple and I am making a trivial mistake somewhere.

I have tried both:
1) Download the foundation.css file and use it directly in the HTML.  Temporarily commenting out the stylesheet inclusion causes Foundation to not work.
2) Include the foundation.scss into my styles.scss file and uncomment the invocation line for the settings file in the foundation.scss file.

The resulting CSS file is:

```
/**
 * Foundation for Sites by ZURB
 * Version 6.5.3
 * foundation.zurb.com
 * Licensed under MIT Open Source
 */
body {
  background-color: orange; }

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow; }

.red {
  background-color: red; }
```

I change the breakpoints in the _settings file to:

```
$breakpoints: (
  small: 0,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1300px,
  xxlarge: 1440px,
);
```

My HTML file is about as simple as it gets:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="grid-x">
    <div class="cell small-6 medium-6 large-6 red">
        this is a div
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-6 medium-6 large-6 show-for-large-only yellow">
        this is a div
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/what-input/5.2.1/what-input.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/js/foundation.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(document).foundation();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My SCSS file is also very simple

```
@import "./scss/foundation.scss";

body {
  background-color: orange;
}

.yellow {

  background-color: yellow;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I believe the compilation to CSS is working because the CSS file is created and the HTML file is displayed with the divs. I believe that the compilation of the Foundation SCSS file is not working because I get nothing but the header when I include the file.

What I would expect is that the yellow div disappear between 1024px and 1300px, but it does not.  It disappears between 1024px and 1200px, the default window for the "large" breakpoint.

Ideas on where I can look for the root cause of my error are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've solved it by now. I had the same problem, setting the `$breakpoints` didn't work for me either. I got it working by setting, for example:

```
$small-breakpoint: 49em;
```

Note you have to set the value in `em`, setting a value in `px` didn't work.